# Is there a way to simulate the system date?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a macro that I only want to run on weekdays. I created the macro that (I'm hoping) will check what day of the week it is and put that into a cell. This is what I have:

```
Private Sub dayCheck()

    If Weekday(Now) = vbMonday Or vbTuesday Or vbWednesday Or vbThursday Or vbFriday Then
        Dim BlankRow As Long
        BlankRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Cells(BlankRow, 1).Select
        Selection.Value = Date
        Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value = Time
        Selection.Offset(0, 2).Value = WeekdayName(Weekday(Now))
        Selection.Offset(0, 3).Value = Environ("Username")

    ElseIf Weekday(Now) = vbSaturday Or vbSunday Then
        Dim time1, time2

        Do
            time1 = Weekday(Now)
            time2 = vbMonday
            Do Until time1 = time2
                DoEvents
                time1 = Now()
            Loop
        Loop

    End If

    Application.OnTime TimeValue("12:00:00"), "dayCheck"

End Sub
```

My problem is I don't have administrator rights to change the system date. Is there a way I can simulate this through a macro?

Comment: To simulate for testing-- which I assume is what you're trying to do-- couldn't you just put this code in a loop that starts with a hard-coded date, and then advances by one day for each iteration?

Comment: You should have better formqtted your code, which would make it easier to read and easier to spot errors.

Comment: Replace the `Now()` function with your own function during testing.

Comment: So instead of `time1 = Now` change it to `time1 = Weekday(1)`? Also, I'm new to writing macros so I don't quite know yet what the typical formatting is. Is there a reference of good formatting I can follow for any future posts?

Comment: `If Weekday(Now) = vbMonday Or vbTuesday Or...` could more easily be `If Weekday(Now) <> vbSaturday AND Weekday(Now) <> vbSunday Then`. Also `If A = B or C or D` won't work in VBA. It has to be `If A = B or A = C or A = D`

Comment: @b.sauer: Try http://rubberduckvba.com/Indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `Now` gives the date/time, `Date` gives just the date.
- `Weekday(Date)` returns the current day number of the week with Sunday being 1.
- As it's Thursday today `Weekday(Now)=vbMonday` will return False.
- `Weekday(Now) = vbMonday Or vbTuesday Or vbWednesday Or vbThursday Or vbFriday` returns 7 - I'm not sure why, but it does.  The main thing here is it doesn't return `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

  - For that statement to work you'd have to use
    `Weekday(Now) = vbMonday Or Weekday(Now) = vbTuesday Or Weekday(Now) = vbWednesday Or Weekday(Now) = vbThursday Or Weekday(Now) = vbFriday`.
    An easier way is `Weekday(Date,vbMonday)<=5` - `vbMonday` numbers the week *Monday = 1, Sunday = 7* and it answers the question "Is date a weekday?".

Here's the code:

```
    Sub Test()

       'DayCheck Now
       'Or
       'DayCheck #11/7/2018 6:55:00 PM#

        'Or look at next 7 days starting now.
        Dim x As Long
        Dim StartDate As Date

        StartDate = Now

        For x = 0 To 6
            DayCheck StartDate + x
        Next x

    End Sub

    Sub DayCheck(MyDate As Date)

        Dim rLastCell As Range
        Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

        Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        If Weekday(MyDate, vbMonday) <= 5 Then
            Set rLastCell = wrkSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) 'Reference to the blank cell itself.
            rLastCell.Resize(, 4) = Array(MyDate, MyDate, MyDate, Environ("Username"))

            rLastCell.NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yy"
            rLastCell.Offset(, 1).NumberFormat = "hh:mm AM/PM"
            rLastCell.Offset(, 2).NumberFormat = "dddd"

        Else 'No need to check if it's a weekend - we know it's not a weekday.

           'Just keep running until time1 = 2 and time2 = 2?
           'I guess that'll be Midnight on Monday?

        End If

    End Sub
```

Note I'm putting the same value in columns `A:C` - just the date and time.
I then format each cell to show the part of the date & time you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate the date code by formatting the general or number output of the now() function in excel and just add 1 to increment the date.  Numbers to the right of the decimal represent the percent of time beyond midnight until the next day.

Today's datetime code is: 43412.37786

Tomorrow is 43413.37786

So your question about testing your code can be answered by creating a for loop with:

```
Dim Today
Today = Now
For Days = Today To Today + 7 'Tests today through next Thursday.
    If Weekday(Days) = ...
Next Days
```

But Darren's answer looks like it solves your problem, so I'd probably just go with that.

Comment: Good point for looping through days - was busy looking at existing code and forgot what the main question was.  Have updated my test code so it loops through 7 days.  Cheers & +1.